# rtmp live streaming issue in android

Tags: android

I am trying to play a rtmp live streaming in Android device.

I have embedded the flash player in webview. Here is streaming url and file.

**URL:** `rtmp://cp86418.live.edgefcs.net/live`

**File Name:** `CatholicTV-LIVE@17230`

As per my knowledge flash should work on the the sdk version higher than 2.2.
The stream is playing all fine some of devices higher than 2.2 like Samsung galaxy tab (model number GT P1010, Sdk version 2.2.1), Samsung T-Mobile (model number SGH-T679, Sdk version 2.3.5) but the strange thing is that, the same thing is not playing in Samsung Ace (model number GT-S5830i, Sdk version 2.3.6) and some of more devices sdk version more than 2.2.

Is there any special thing to do with the devices which are not playing live streaming? or some more plugins or coding required?

Can some one help me out from this difficult situation by sharing their valuable suggestions and advice.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, just give you the logic to check if Flash available.

```
private boolean isFlashAvailable(){
    String version;
    try {
        version = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.adobe.flashplayer", 0).versionName;
        Log.d(TAG, "Flash installed version = " + version);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No flash installed!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in your manifest file. My problem was solved this way.

```
   <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Comment: Yes! In my app android:minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="15". Have you checked if those devices have flash installed?

Comment: r u sure flash installation is mandatory in order to embed flash in web view?

Comment: I think so because it my app, the device w/o flash did not work. I can give you the logic to check if flash is installed if you need it.

Comment: thanks for logic..can u do one more favore to me..pleas share the google play link, from where you have downloaded the adobe flash player..

Comment: Here is the link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer . First run the logic to see if Flash is installed or not. If not install flash

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem with android versions and video playback. I think the cause is from a combination of android version and hardware. I was not able to stream, even in the native player embedded in an activity, videos on the Galaxy Ace, Galaxy Mini, ZTE Blade, and some other low-end devices. The common denominator is all the devices have android version 2.2 or lower. When I upgraded the Galaxy Mini and Galaxy Ace to 2.3 (even unofficial rom), I was able to get it playing smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not the solution of this burning issue, but i found a url where the flash supported devices are listed.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flashruntimes/certified-devices.html

And exactly only those devices are supporting the flash in web view which are listed in the above url. 
Hope this will solve some issue too..